# The function is not redirecting to the right screen

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a function inside my app that suppose to delete the picture and redirect the user to HomeScreen. But nothing happens when the photo deleted, its stays on the same screen

My code:

```
onDelete = (photo) => {
        const photoKey = photo.photo.key;
        this.refs.deletePopup.close();

        api.getToken()
        .then(token => api.deleteSafee(photoKey, token))
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
            const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
                index: 0,
                actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: "Home", params: {
                    isRefreshFeed: true
                }})],
            });

            this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)                             
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            showError("Delete Error", error.message);
        });             
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us how you call this function?

Comment: I think the `routeName` should be in  `NavigationActions.reset` itslef. The routName in `actions` is a sub-action to run in the child router

Comment: @AliSheikhpour can you please include some code?

Comment: const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({routeName: "Home", params: {isRefreshFeed: true},index: 0 });

Comment: so what you mean, I should get rid of all this : const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: "Home", params: {
     isRefreshFeed: true
    }})],
   });

Comment: @sanjar I believe this way :
 onDelete = (photo) => {
  const photoKey = photo.photo.key;
  this.refs.deletePopup.close();